# "Uninitialized value" on size of the link

Tags: c++, file, filesystems, symlink

I am trying to print the size of the files in current directory , i am using this function to get the size

```
string filesize( const char * filename){
    ostringstream os;
    struct stat buf;
    stat(filename, &buf);
    if( buf.st_size > 1000000000){
         os << setprecision(2) << fixed << (float)buf.st_size/1024000 <<"mb";
    }else if( buf.st_size > 1024){
         os << setprecision(2) << fixed <<  (float)buf.st_size / 1024 <<"kb";

    }else{
         os  << buf.st_size <<"bt"; 
    }
        return os.str();    
}
```

and this piece of code to get the list of files and print their size

```
DIR *dir;
dirent *pdir;
dir=opendir(".");
int det;

while((pdir=readdir(dir))){
    cout <<  filesize(pdir -> d_name) << endl;

}
```

which works just fine. The only problem is when the directory contains symbolic link that points to the file that is not in current directory e.g

in `/sandbox/tests`  there is a sym link that points to the file that is in

```
/school/work
```

in that case , this piece of code throws tons of error regarding

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> Use of uninitialised value of size 8

Why is this problem occuring ? Is there any way how to fix this? I am trying to figure it out but cannot find any solution

Comment: Initialise your variables.

Comment: @molbdnilo I do not see any uninitialised variables, also if there were any obvious unintialised variables , wouldnt it throw this error on every file not just on sym links that point to different directories?

Comment: @trolkura `struct stat buf;` is uninitialized.  And you're not checking if your `stat()` call succeeds or fails.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Wouldnt it throw error everytime then? Not just when sym link that points to another directory is present? Also according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html it is valid declaration of that struct.

Comment: @trolkura `struct stat buf;` is a valid definition of an uninitialized structure.  If the `stat` call succeeds, it fills in the structure.  If the call fails, the structure contents remain uninitialized.